# Is this expression mathematically correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{x} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$$

If $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{x^2} a_{n}$ is known to be convergent, is this statement mathematically correct?

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{x^2} a_{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2} a_{n} $$

Comment: It is not so much that the statement is incorrect as that it is nonsensical, until you define the meaning of the right-hand side when the upper limit is infinity -- in which case you'll find yourself right back at the left-hand side.

Comment: Just edited the question to include the requested definition, per the accepted convention.

Answer (score 2):

I'll use $N$ instead of $x$, since $N$ is more typical to use with an upper limit and as a natural number.

If we replaced $N^2$ with a more general $f(N)$, where $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is some increasing function, then this would be the question:

> Consider the sequence of partial sums $\left( \sum_{n=0}^N{a_n}\right)_N$. If some subsequence of this converges, i.e. $\lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{f(N)}{a_n}}$ converges, then does the entire sequence converge, i.e. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_N}$ converges?

Phrased in this way, it is relatively easy to guess that the answer is wrong, and we can give an example to show this.

Consider for example 
$$ a_n = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n=N^2$ for some $N$} \\ -1 & \text{if $n=N^2+1$ for some $N>0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then $\sum_{n=0}^{N^2}{a_n}=2$ for $N>0$. Hence, $\lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n=0}^{N^2}{a_n}}=2$.

However, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}$ does not converge, since it fluctuates between the values $1$ and $2$ infinitely-often.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks. Given your input, I am going to edit my question so that quantity of the left hand side is known to converge.

Comment: @Math12345 My example does have the left-hand limit converging, while the right one does not. In fact, we have equality if and only if the right one also converges; this is a standard fact about sequences and subsequences. If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same limit

Comment: How did you know that the second to last expression was equal to 2?

Comment: I constructed it to be that way. The first two terms of the sequence are $1$, giving the contribution of $2$. After that point, every time we reach a perfect square $(N+1)^2$, we'll get a $-1$ from $N^2+1$ and a $+1$ from $(N+1)^2$, hence they cancel and you're left with the $2$ you started with.

Comment: Ok, I understand your point now. The sum fluctuates, but the limit does not. However, what if a_n is defined such that it does not fluctuate? Maybe a_n is a monotonically increasing function, or a monotonically decreasing function. Would you agree that there may be a case in which the answer to my question is yes, or is the answer always no?

Comment: Also, as a side note, would your argument suggest that the very first equation in my question is not always correct?

Comment: I would also like to add that "lim s_n = s" according to p.102 of *Theory and Application of Infinite Series* by Konrad Knopp.

Comment: Your first equation is a definition (though I think as written it is a bit misleading, since when using $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ suggest $x\in\mathbb{R}$), so it's always true. If $a_n$ is monotonic, then your proposed equation is true, as in this case the partial sums will also be monotonic and if a sequence is monotonic and one of its subsequences is convergent, then the whole thing is convergent. This follows from the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Answer (score 0):

No - the latter would imply you're taking the sum's value, whereas the former implies you're actually taking the limit of the sum itself.

The top of the sum in the latter can be replaced by $\infty$, whereas doing the same with the former wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: I just edited the question to provide more background information...